# Euro currency character not displaying

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin

I've built a xamarin iOs application. In one of my controller, I do something like this:

```
LabelId.Text = myDouble.ToString("##0.00€");
```

If I run the application from Visual Studio 2013 (on my windows computer paired with a mac), the application (on the simulator and on the device) displays the "€" symbol.

However, when I run it from xamarin on the mac, the € symbol is replaced by a square on the device and by something unrelated on the simulator.
If I replace it by a dollar "$". It's ok.

Does anyone know how to display the euro symbol when using Xamarin on a mac?

Thank you

Comment: What are the region / locale settings on the MAC?

Comment: Try displaying the current culture currency symbol... what does the MAC give?

Comment: The region is set to "France"

Comment: In the editor, I have the "€" symbol

Comment: This may prove helpful to you... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: The font has a euro symbol?

Comment: I tried to change the font to "Courier" or "Didot" but I didn't succeed. @PaulZahra gave me the right input  and myDouble.ToString("c", new CultureInfo("fr-FR")) works fine. You can add an answer so that I mark solved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx Suggests that you need to create a new CultureInfo object and set the currency symbol through that.

Comment: What I exactly did is to modify the toString to `myDouble.ToString("c", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))` Thanks